# Protocol/requirements for repeat visits to a Shiv'ah house

Tags: mourning-aveilus, sitting-shiva, friendship

What are the Protocol/requirements for repeat visits to a Shiv'ah house?

Are there any formalities that can be set aside (letting them speak first, sitting with them, as opposed to chatting by the coffee pot in the kitchen, etc.)? 
Do you say HaMakom each time? Do you have to make sure you say it to each Avel?

This is not a question about family members of the Avelim or community volunteers organizing the Shiv'ah. Just repeat visitors - Minyan regulars, close-ish friends, etc.